# Sprite animation handler

Tags: c#, game, animation, xna

When a user presses a key in my game, their avatar can move down, left, right or up. By move, I mean their avatar animates while various other things move around them on the screen. This is accomplished by raising an event from the `InputHandler` class.

```
public class InputHandler
{
    public delegate void ActionListener(Actions action);

    public event ActionListener ActionRequested;

    public void ProcessKeyboard(KeyboardState keyboardState)
    {
        var keys = keyboardState.GetPressedKeys().ToList();

        if (!keys.Any())
        {
            ActionRequested(Actions.Idle);
            return;
        }

        foreach (var action in keys.Select(GetAction))
        {
            ActionRequested(action);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Player` class listens for the `ActionRequested` event:

```
public class Player
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Sprite> sprites;

    public Player(IEnumerable<Sprite> sprites)
    {
        this.sprites = sprites;
    }

    public void Listen(Actions action)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case Actions.Idle:
                Idle();
                return;

            case Actions.MoveDown:
            case Actions.MoveLeft:
            case Actions.MoveRight:
            case Actions.MoveUp:
                Animate(action);
                return;
        }
    }

    public void Idle()
    {
        foreach (var sprite in sprites)
        {
            sprite.Idle();
        }
    }

    public void Animate(Actions action)
    {
        foreach (var sprite in sprites)
        {
            sprite.Animate(action);
        }
    }
}
```

When the `Animate` method is called on the `Sprite` class, it gets the `Animation` for that `Action` (`MoveDown`, `MoveLeft`, etc.), gets the next frame from that `Animation` and resets the previous animation (so it doesn't start halfway through the next time the button is pressed). The `Idle` method moves the frame to the left-most position in the sprite sheet (so the avatar is standing still and not frozen mid-animation). Think of the frame as a viewport for the sprite sheet.

```
public class Sprite
{
    private Rectangle frame;
    private readonly IDictionary<Actions, Animation> animations;
    private Animation prevAnimation;

    public Sprite(Rectangle frame, IDictionary<Actions, Animation> animations)
    {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.animations = animations;
    }

    public void Idle()
    {
        frame.X = 0;
    }

    public void Animate(Actions action)
    {
        Animation animation;

        if (!animations.TryGetValue(action, out animation))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!animation.IsReady())
        {
            return;
        }

        frame = animation.GetNextFrame();

        if (animation == prevAnimation)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (prevAnimation != null)
        {
            prevAnimation.Reset();
        }

        prevAnimation = animation;
    }
}
```

The `Animation` class itself is really just a list of frames (`Rectangle`s). The `IsReady` method updates the timer (only one frame can be returned every 100ms or so, so the avatar doesn't act like a cracked out monkey). The `GetNextFrame` method updates the current frame number and returns the next one in the sequence.

```
public class Animation
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Rectangle> frames;
    private int currentFrame = 1;
    private double frameTimer = 0;
    private const double frameSpeed = 0.2;

    public Animation(IEnumerable<Rectangle> frames)
    {
        this.frames = frames;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        currentFrame = 1;
        frameTimer = 0;
    }

    public bool IsReady()
    {
        if (frameTimer == 0)
        {
            frameTimer += frameSpeed;
            return true;
        }

        if (frameTimer < frameInterval)
        {
            frameTimer += frameSpeed;
            return false;
        }

        frameTimer = 0;
        return false;
    }

    public Rectangle GetNextFrame()
    {
        if (currentFrame == frames.Count())
        {
            currentFrame = 1;

            return frames.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        currentFrame++;

        return frames.ElementAtOrDefault(currentFrame - 1);
    }
}
```

Finally here's a typical sprite sheet, which I got from [Liberated Pixel Cup](http://lpc.opengameart.org/). Each row is an animation for one direction (up, left, down right), and the far left column (`frame.X = 0`) is the standing position. The actual animations don't include this first column because it makes it look all janky.

[image]

This works pretty well and I'm happy with it for the most part. I have a few issues that I'm not sure how to improve:

1. `InputHandler` raises an event for what is essentially a non-action when there is no input detected, which means it is almost constantly telling the Player to Idle.
2. I don't like that there's a hard-coded requirement in the `Idle` method of the `Sprite` class for every sprite sheet to reserve its left-most column for an avatar's standing position. Not every sprite sheet is a humanoid anyways.
3. I don't like that the `Animate` method is responsible for resetting the previous animation - I have NO idea how else to do this, since I can't detect when a user stops pressing a key.
4. I'm not sure if the `IsReady` method of the `Animation` class should update `frameTimer` or just check the value of `frameTimer` and return true of false.
5. Similarly, I'm not sure if the `GetNextFrame` method should update `currentFrame` or just return the next frame in the sequence.

Comment: Are you asking how to fix this issues in your current design or how to implement a better design?

Comment: I'm looking for a code review. Whatever that includes is fine.

Answer (score 11):

Looks pretty neat overall, I merely glanced at your code (favorited, I want to look at this more deeply, as I'm [*playing with* | *learning*] XNA myself, your XNA posts are very useful!).

One thing I've noticed, I don't think you need this `switch` block:

```
public void Listen(Actions action)
{
    switch (action)
    {
        case Actions.Idle:
            Idle();
            return;

        case Actions.MoveDown:
        case Actions.MoveLeft:
        case Actions.MoveRight:
        case Actions.MoveUp:
            Animate(action);
            return;
    }
}
```

Instead, I'd probably do this:

```
public void Listen(Actions action)
{
    Animate(action);
}
```

...and in `Animate(Actions)` I'd add the call to `Idle()` and exit `if (action == Actions.Idle)`. "Being idle" *does* involve choosing a location on the sprite sheet, I don't see why it would be handled in `Listen` when everything else is in `Animate`.

Also in `switch` blocks you should use `break;`, and let the function `return` by itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your `GetNextFrame` should have fewer `if` statements.  In other words, you should merge some of them together.  The ones that return early should especially be in an `if ..then .. else if.. then` structure, like this.  It works either way, but this looks cleaner and is more to the point about what the code does.

```
public Rectangle GetNextFrame(GameActions gameAction)
{
    var sequence = GetSequence(gameAction);
    if (gameAction == GameActions.Idle) {
        frameTimer = 0;

        prevFrame.X = 0;
        prevGameAction = gameAction;

        return prevFrame;
    } else if(frameTimer != 0) {
        UpdateTimer();

        return prevFrame;
    } else if (sequence == null) {
        return prevFrame;
    }

    UpdateTimer();

    Rectangle nextFrame;

    if (gameAction != prevGameAction)
    {
        nextFrame = sequence.First();
    }
    else
    {
        nextFrame = sequence.Next(prevFrame);
    }

    prevFrame = nextFrame;
    prevGameAction = gameAction;

    return nextFrame;
}
```

Your `Animate` method has some extra lines in it as well where the `if` statements can be merged together.

```
public void Animate(Actions action)
{
    Animation animation;

    if (!animations.TryGetValue(action, out animation) || !animation.IsReady())
    {
        return;
    }

    frame = animation.GetNextFrame();

    if (animation == prevAnimation)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (prevAnimation != null)
    {
        prevAnimation.Reset();
    }

    prevAnimation = animation;
}
```

That one `if` statement with the OR clause `||` does the exact same thing that your code did, but with fewer lines and in a cleaner manner.

Comment: sorry, some of this was from yesterday, I forgot to finish it.  I haven't had a chance to read the updates on the question yet either